# URL-encoding and HTML-encoding NSStrings

Tags: iphone, encoding, nsstring, urlencode, html-entities

Is their a method to encode/decode HTML and URL (in Xcode, using Objective-C)?

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:<#(NSString *)path#> encoding:<#(NSStringEncoding)enc#> error:<#(NSError **)error#>]
```

This doesn't seem to work how i expected. I thought it will convert special characters like "<" to equivalent HTML entities i.e. "<" in this case.

Here's a reference to the w3school link related to this topic (general):

[HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

[HTML Entities Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)

Thanking in anticipation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Returns a representation of the receiver using a given encoding to determine the percent escapes necessary to convert the receiver into a legal URL string.

```
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

and

Returns a new string made by replacing in the receiver all percent escapes with the matching characters as determined by a given encoding.

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Comment: Read the other answers for methods to quote strings as XML (i.e., entity replacement and < to &lt;)

Answer (score 11):

The method you cite reads a file from disk with a given character encoding (such as UTF-8 or ASCII).  It has nothing to do with URL or HTML escaping.

If you want to add URL percent escapes, you want this method:

```
[myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Make sure you read the documentation about this method, because there are certain subtleties about what it escapes and what it leaves alone.  In some cases, you may have to use the more complex, but more flexible, `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()`.  (If you do, note that you can cast `CFStringRef` to `NSString *` and vice versa.)

There's nothing built in that I know of to do XML/HTML-style entity escaping, but this function ought to handle the basics:

```
NSString * convertToXMLEntities(NSString * myString) {
    NSMutableString * temp = [myString mutableCopy];

    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&"
                          withString:@"&amp;"
                             options:0
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<"
                          withString:@"&lt;"
                             options:0
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@">"
                          withString:@"&gt;"
                             options:0
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\""
                          withString:@"&quot;"
                             options:0
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"'"
                          withString:@"&apos;"
                             options:0
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];

    return [temp autorelease];
}
```

Comment: If I were writing this for my own code, I would actually have defined a -replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString: method in a category on NSMutableString and used that to avoid the repetition. (I would probably have written this as an NSMutableString method instead of a function, too, come to think of it.)  But I didn't want to include too much in this.

Comment: It's correct except that it doesn't discuss HTML entities (which the original poster also asked about) and doesn't mention the limitations of NSString's methods for doing this (which have screwed me at least twice).  But for basic URL encoding, yes, it's a perfectly good answer.

Comment: It's subtly important that '&' is replaced first!

Comment: kookie "rose garden" alignment is by far the best part of objective-C.  F the ["Apple Style Guidelines"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/APStyleGuide/APSG_2009.pdf)!  Make it look like a trellis, that's what I say!

Comment: Actually, @alexgray, I've since stopped doing this. I now use a variable width font when coding (I find it's easier on the eyes), so letters are no longer a specific number of spaces or tabs wide, and I can't line up colons anymore. My style has changed as a result; I don't use hard returns in statements and instead let Xcode wrap lines for me.

Comment: Sacrilege!  I'm betting [that you haven't tried Ubuntu mono, though](http://font.ubuntu.com/#charset-mono-regular)... THE *best* monospaced font..  ever.  It makes all other's virtually illegible.  Free.  And comes with a **BOLD** variant... yee haw!

Comment: Ubunto Mono has some pretty letter shapes, but I'm not looking for pretty letter shapes, I'm looking for something that reads like printed text (but with distinguishable punctuation). No monospaced font can achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

To do HTML/XML entity encoding, you can use a CFMutableString function:

`NSString *result = .....;

CFStringTransform((CFMutableStringRef)result, NULL, kCFStringTransformToXMLHex, false);`

By setting the last parameter of CFStringTransform to true, it should work for decoding (hex) entities as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use `CFStringTransform` for HTML entity encoding/decoding:

`CFStringTransform((CFTypeRef)yourMutableString, NULL, CFSTR("Any-Hex/XML"), FALSE );`

You need to use the ICU transform "Any-Hex/XML". `kCFStringTransformToXMLHex` isn't aggressive enough.

Comment: What kind of entities are missed by kCFStringTransformToXMLHex?

Comment: @StevenKramer For example, > or &.