# '?' in strings breaking my XML parser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing

The parsing of a file containing XML breaks when ever there is a string containing '?'. As an example you can see the  line below.

```
<Radio id="32">
<stationName>BBC 5 Live</stationName>
<streamType>aac+</streamType>
<streamBandwidth>48kbps</streamBandwidth>
<streamURL>http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_he2_5live_q?s=1308038932&e=1308053332&h=868e4fa343b375695183f6a3bd0267d9</streamURL>
</Radio>
```

Is there some way to encode the '?' or what is the way thats generally used to handle this kind of problem, as I would imagine this would be encountered a lot.

The line of code that handles this (i believe) is :

```
[aRadio setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
```

Though I maybe that is not where it breaks.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, the problem is not the '?' character, but the '&' characters in your URL. The '&' character has a special meaning in XML (it is used to start entities like `&amp;` or `&lt;`), so the XML parser will fail if it doesn't find a valid entity. The way to go is to wrap the value in a CDATA section as deanWombourne suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Convert it into UTF8

```
NSData *data = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then parse with this data...

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways of dealing with this.

1) Percent encode the string before sending from the server (your '?' would become '%3F') and decode the data when you receive in in your app. - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667206/cocoa-iphone-programming-encoding-decoding-nsstring/1667612#1667612) for more details.

2) Use CDATA markers around this bit of data - [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) for more details