# NSFileManager moveItemAtPath:toPath:error: changes filename

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, nsfilemanager

I have a importFile stored at NSString* importFile (printed with NSLog %@):

```
/var/mobile/Applications/5CE1D252-E56A-4AAC-B88E-5B0CEFFF55B3/Library/Caches/tmp/temp_695D39E3-3359-415F-9C0D-243E2E117B8B-456-0000001384C17BBA.tmpfile
```

I then receive a destinationFile NSString * destinationFile a value of (printed with NSLog %@)

```
/var/mobile/Applications/5CE1D252-E56A-4AAC-B88E-5B0CEFFF55B3/Documents/Str%208829%20-%20Test.500887280
```

then I use NSFileManager to move the file:

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
assert(fileManager != nil);
NSError* error = nil;
[fileManager moveItemAtPath:importFile toPath:destinationFile error:&error];
```

the problem is that the actual file's name after the move is different from the requested destinationFile:

```
Str%25208829%2520-%2520Test.500887280
```

what's going on here ? what are those extra three 25 that seem to be the difference ?

Comment: The %25 is a replacement for the % characters.

Comment: Show the code for how you setup `importFile` and `destinationFile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `%` in the filename is being encoded as `%25` (the percent code for percent)

You might check this one out:
[URL-encoding and HTML-encoding NSStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667206/cocoa-iphone-programming-encoding-decoding-nsstring)

Comment: Thank you. There indeed were "interesting" things done to the destinationFile file name and how it was created. I have replaced those with better character filtering  and now things are looking good again. Thanks for the tips again.

Answer (score 1):

you have to define the file type and extension. Then you just have to move the file from one directory to another ... You can also rename the file

```
NSFileManager *manage = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Documents/%@",Text.txt];
NSString *newPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Documents/%@",newText.txt];

[manage moveItemAtPath:path toPath:newPath error:&error];
```